# C# WPF button navigation to a usercontrol page returns null

Tags: c#, wpf, button, navigation

i have this code here in my mainwindow :

```
  private void btnHome_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this).Navigate("home.xaml");
    }
```

home.xaml is my user control page which i want the button to navigate to , but when i click it , the whole thing crashes and i debug it , it shows NullException.

What actually gone wrong?
I am able to run the MainWindow and home.xaml separately well.

Comment: Isn't Navigate argument an Uri? / And you need to have your user control to be on some page... It doesn't exist until you create it.

Comment: Do i have to add it into the mainwindow? how do i add it?

Comment: It depends on your application design. You can put your user control on main window, yes. But as you asked about navigation here is how you design basic application with pages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752299.aspx . Your question is missing details so I can't be sure what's your problem and how to  answer.

Comment: Basically now i have a user control page and mainwindow only . I just want to know how do i go to the user control page from mainwindow's button . Pardon me becoz i am new to this . Becos i tot it will be as simple as response.redirect between pages in web application , but it seems it doesn't work that way .

Comment: Try to put Frame inside your MainWindow and Navigate. example(  frame1.NavigationService.Navigate("Home.xaml"));